# Read/Write XLSM using POI

Tags: c#, excel, npoi, xlsm

I'm using POI in my c# code for few weeks, and i've found and issue i don't manage to solve: Xlsm.

I've to open an xlsm template, edit it and save it. The template contains Macro, but i just add data into the xlsm file.
Actually, I think that Read and Edit are working find (thanks to debugging in vs), the issue is when I try to write...
The code is working, there is no error, but when I Try to open it with Excel, it crashes..

```
FileStream temp = new FileStream(xlsm_file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
XSSFWorkbook workbook = (XSSFWorkbook)WorkbookFactory.Create(temp);
XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet)workbook.GetSheetAt(0);
workbook.SetSheetName(0, sheetname.Substring(0, Math.Min(sheetname.Length, 30)));
temp.Close();
FileStream toWrite = new FileStream(xlsm_file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
workbook.Write(toWrite);
toWrite.Close();
```

for example, even this crashes..

Is anyone having an Idea?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

you need to write your macro embedded file in appropriate format for example I read .xltm file and write with its MIME type of .xltm . see the below function

```
     public ActionResult DownloadXLTMFile()
            {
                try
                {
                  //Get your macro enabled file after manipulation
                   MemoryStream excelMS =  .....
                   //Using Resposne Stream to Make File Available for User to Download;
                    Response.Clear();

                    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12";
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}",  "YourFileName.xltm"));

                    Response.BinaryWrite(excelMS.ToArray());
                    Response.End();
                }
                catch (Exception Ex)
                {  }
                finally
                {}
                return View();
            }
```

you can find your appropriate MIME type [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsofficedeveloper/2008/05/08/office-2007-file-format-mime-types-for-http-content-streaming-2/)